# GCP Terminology - VMs, Instances, Workers, Nodes

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm a little bit confused about the equivalency of some terms in GCP. Can we consider VM = instance and these equivalent to Workers and Nodes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can interpret the terms like this:

- Instance: a (virtual) machine with fixed CPU, memory and disk resources
- Worker: a non-permanent, dynamically provisioned ad-hoc instance
- Node: instance that belongs to an instance group / Kubernetes cluster
- VM: any virtual machine - i.e. applies to all above